# Swift 4.2 Syntax change - What happened to Swift type inference?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10

I'm running Xcode 10 beta with Swift 4.2. Xcode wants to convert my Xcode 9.4.1 with Swift 4.1 code to Swift 4.2 syntax. The changes are all `UIView.animate(... options: ...)`.

I using options like `.curveEaseIn` which worked fine before but it wants to change them to `UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn`.

What happened to Swift's ENUM type inference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was `UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn` in Swift 4.1. So, the migrator has detected your `.curveEaseIn` as `UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn` and trying to convert it to `UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn`.

Seems current migrator does not like dot-leaded notation.

You can convert all occurrences of `UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn` into `.curveEaseIn` manually, and Swift type inference would work if appropriate.

You may want to write a [feature request](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) proposing improvement of the migrator.

---

(Addition)
Seems Xcode 10 beta 3 has fixed this issue, though I have not tested yet.

[Xcode 10 beta 3 Release Notes](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_beta_3/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_10_beta_3.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

`AnimationOptions` is a enum under UIView now in swift 4.2

You can also take a look at this git repo which contains a list of syntax changes.
Please feel free to contribute with the changes you've met in your project.

https://github.com/alexliubj/Swift-Migration-4.2